# Postgresql : which way is faster DISTINCT or GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 2 ways to do the same thing.

Example: get distinct names from persons database

The first way is:

```
SELECT name 
FROM person 
GROUP BY name
```

Has the same result as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM person
```

What I am curious of, is there anything different in the way an Postgresql SQL engine processes the command and which way is faster, or are they doing the same thing?

Comment: DISTINCT is better, GROUP BY is for SUM / AVERAGE / or others for the calculating the group

Comment: In theory they should be the same, however GROUP BY can use parallel query while DISTINCT can not. So there might be situations where GROUP BY is faster.

Comment: There's also a 3:rd way: `SELECT name FROM person UNION SELECT name FROM person`. But I'd go with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Why must it be fast? It is a trivial query. (in a non-trivial query, `DISTINCT` would raise red flags)

Comment: The answer to this question will necessarily depend on the data and the environment in which the query is running. I suggest that you run your own benchmarks.

Answer (score 6):

For only a few records (f.e. 100000) it doesn't really matter.
Both will use the same HashAggregate method.

And then a golfcoder would prefere `DISTINCT` because it has a bit shorter syntax.
The `GROUP BY` is more intended to be used with aggregation functions anyway, like MAX, SUM, COUNT, AVG, ...

But for a larger recordset there's a difference.

For example in this demo

> ```
> create table Persons (
>  Name varchar(30)
> )
>
> INSERT INTO Persons (Name)
> SELECT
>     arrays.firstnames[s.a % ARRAY_LENGTH(arrays.firstnames,1) + 1]
>  || arrays.lastnames[s.a % ARRAY_LENGTH(arrays.lastnames,1) + 1] AS name
> FROM     generate_series(1,600000) AS s(a) -- number of names to generate
> CROSS JOIN(
>     SELECT ARRAY[
>     'Adam','Bill','Bob','Calvin','Donald','Dwight','Frank','Fred','George','Howard',
>     'James','John','Jacob','Jack','Martin','Matthew','Max','Michael','Lukas', 
>     'Paul','Peter','Phil','Roland','Ronald','Samuel','Steve','Theo','Warren','William',
>     'Abigail','Alice','Allison','Amanda','Anne','Barbara','Betty','Carol','Cleo','Donna',
>     'Jane','Jennifer','Julie','Martha','Mary','Melissa','Patty','Sarah','Simone','Susan'
>     ] AS firstnames,
>     ARRAY[
>         'Matthews','Smith','Jones','Davis','Jacobson','Williams','Donaldson','Maxwell','Peterson','Storms','Stevens',
>         'Franklin','Washington','Jefferson','Adams','Jackson','Johnson','Lincoln','Grant','Fillmore','Harding','Taft',
>         'Truman','Nixon','Ford','Carter','Reagan','Bush','Clinton','Hancock'
>     ] AS lastnames
> ) AS arrays
> ```

> ```
> select count(*) from Persons
> ```
>
> ```
> |  count |
> | -----: |
> | 600000 |
> ```

> ```
> explain analyse
> select distinct Name from Persons
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | HashAggregate  (cost=6393.82..6395.82 rows=200 width=78) (actual time=194.609..194.757 rows=1470 loops=1)            |
> |   Group Key: name                                                                                                    |
> |   ->  Seq Scan on persons  (cost=0.00..5766.66 rows=250866 width=78) (actual time=0.030..61.243 rows=600000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.259 ms                                                                                              |
> | Execution time: 194.898 ms                                                                                           |
> ```

> ```
> explain analyse
> select Name from Persons group by Name
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                      |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Group  (cost=5623.88..5625.88 rows=200 width=78) (actual time=226.358..227.145 rows=1470 loops=1)                                               |
> |   Group Key: name                                                                                                                               |
> |   ->  Sort  (cost=5623.88..5624.88 rows=400 width=78) (actual time=226.356..226.596 rows=4410 loops=1)                                          |
> |         Sort Key: name                                                                                                                          |
> |         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 403kB                                                                                                   |
> |         ->  Gather  (cost=5564.59..5606.59 rows=400 width=78) (actual time=206.700..219.546 rows=4410 loops=1)                                  |
> |               Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                |
> |               Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                               |
> |               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=4564.59..4566.59 rows=200 width=78) (actual time=196.862..197.072 rows=1470 loops=3)             |
> |                     Group Key: name                                                                                                             |
> |                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on persons  (cost=0.00..4303.27 rows=104528 width=78) (actual time=0.039..66.876 rows=200000 loops=3) |
> | Planning time: 0.069 ms                                                                                                                         |
> | Execution time: 227.301 ms                                                                                                                      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f080e45c0952d9cf41871e8ac7638ab4)*

So in this example the DISTINCT was still faster.
But since the GROUP BY started to work in parallel, that might also depend on the server that hosts the postgresql.

Comment: On my DEV machine (MacOS), the parallel GROUP BY is consistently faster, twice as fast. Tested on PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: Also 2 workers on your DEV?   And thanks for informing, as this kinda proves the point that it can depend on the postgres server where you run it.